# Solve $\int_C(2z^2+8z+1)dz$ with parametric curves $x = a (\theta- \sin\theta)$ and $y = a (1 - \cos\theta)$

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-integration

Find integral
$$\int_C(2z^2+8z+1)dz$$
where $C$ is the parametric curve
$$x = a (\theta- \sin\theta)$$
$$y = a (1 - \cos\theta)$$
$$0 \le\theta\le 2\pi$$

What i've been taught it to make the whole integral in $\theta$. So basically to get this:
$$\int^{2\pi}_0f(\theta)d\theta$$
I've so far gotten $$z = a(\theta - \sin\theta + i - i\cos\theta)$$
$$\frac{dz}{d\theta}= a(1-\cos\theta +i\sin\theta)$$

My only problem is that there will be quite a lot of work to change $2z^2+8z+1$ in terms of $\theta$. So i'm just checking if what i'm doing is right or is there a different method i should be looking at.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint. Let $F(z):=\frac{2z^3}{3}+4z^2+z$ then $\frac{dF}{dz}(z)=f(z):=2z^2+8z+1$.
Therefore
\begin{align}\int_Cf(z)dz&=\int_0^{2\pi}f(z(\theta))\frac{dz}{d\theta}d\theta
=\int_0^{2\pi}\frac{dF}{dz}(z(\theta))\frac{dz}{d\theta} d\theta\\
&=\int_0^{2\pi}\frac{d(F(z(\theta))}{d\theta}d\theta=F(z(2\pi))-F(z(0))
=F(2\pi a)-F(0).
\end{align}

Comment: Hmm... So you are suggesting i change $(2z^2+8z+1)dz=d(\frac{2z^3}{3}+4z^2+z)$? Can't quite see how that would help. Sorry i'm pretty new to this

Comment: @Danxe See my revised answer. Any further doubt?

Comment: I am actually going through it now, trying to make sense of it. I more or less got it by where to the parametric equations come into the picture though? is it when evaluating z(2pi) and z(0)?

Comment: For such $f$ the integral does not depend on the curve between the enpoints. Yes, in this case the parametric equations are needed just to evaluate $z(2\pi)$ and $z(0)$.

Comment: That's great to know! Thank you so much!